# Other uses of shortest path algorithm in Neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j

I understand using the shortest path algorithm for find the fastest way to travel from node A to node Z, but in presentation by the ICIJ journalist at GraphConnect on the SwissLeaks data, how would the shortest path have been used to uncover spurious account activity?

Answer (score 0):

You probably would pick suspect nodes and see how they are connected, e.g. to mark other people between them also with a suspect weight which is incremented each time a person is on such a path.

You would probably use allShortestPaths then.

Also use shortest-path to compute betweenness centrality between a number of nodes. Which nodes are repeatedly found on paths between other nodes.

Comment: ah thanks for responding Michael.  I guess I am still getting my head around shortest path benefits.  The Swiss Leaks investigation exposed the benefitting clients, who would have been as far removed from the original bank account as possible across various jurisdictions.  For exampe Account A might be created by False Customer X to offshore company in a different jurisdictions that could be owned by FalseHoldingsCompany Y etc etc .

So I would expect the longest path between account and benefitting client would have been set up